# How to find the triangles resulting from clipping a triangle against a convex polygon.

Tags: geometry, algorithms

We have a 2D triangle. It has 3 points.

We have a 2D convex polygon. It has N points.

Normally when clipping, one wants to produce the polygon or list of triangles inside the convex polygon. I want to do the opposite. I want to get the list of triangles that do not intersect aside from bordering edges, and are NOT within the convex polygon and result from clipping.

For example if I had a triangle with a square completely enclosed within, I would want to get the list of triangles representing the triangle with a square missing from the center.

Comment: Why just having a triangle with a side as base and outside the polygon? N such triangles.

Comment: I see an option of 2 and option of 3... could you make a drawing?

Comment: If I understand your question - you can have the square in right angle triangle - two sides of square on the right angle or one side of square on one side of the triangle.

Comment: Look at the example and draw the example - you get infinite number of triangles.

Comment: Are you asking how to do the **not** operation ("Triangle **not** Polygon") as described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons?

Comment: I wanted to clarify what you mean. Since it may be unclear to others too, including the actual terminology of the operation you are asking about will make it much clearer what you are asking for (the concept is well known to people that write geometric algorithms and may best be able to help you). So yes, edit :)

Answer (score 1):

First find all triangle-polygon intersections.

[image]

Then you should be able to tell if a vertex of the polygon is inside the triangle or not.

To build exterior triangles you use the intersection points and those polygon-vertices inside the triangle.

The point is which of the three red vertices use as third vertex for a exterior triangle.

Use the condition that no edge (green) can cross any edge of the polygon.

---

For the case where the given clipping triangle encloses completely the polygon, so there are no intersections:

[image]

To build any of the exterior triangles (green), get an edge of the polygon (blue) and one of the vertices of the enclosing triangle.

The point is which of the three enclosing vertices use as third vertex.

Use the condition that no edge (green) can cross any edge of the polygon.

---

Notice that the not-crossing condition can be used even for other cases like:
[image]